# Notepad++ regular expression replace with slashes and numbers

Tags: regex, replace, expression, notepad++

I'm facing the following problem. I'm trying to replace several paths from config files. These files contains a list of pathnames (one per line), like this:

`\\some_server\a_resource\some_library\latest\name_of_the_library.dll`
`\\some_server\a_resource\other_library\latest\name_of_other_library.dll`

I want to replace every line with this:

`\\some_server\a_resource\some_library\2.1\name_of_the_library.dll`
`\\some_server\a_resource\other_library\2.1\name_of_other_library.dll`

So, I use notepad++ to replace that in all files but here is the problem.

The regular expression I use is this:

`\\\\some_server\\a_resource\\(.*)\\latest\\`

and I want to replace it with:

`\\some_server\a_resource\\1\2.1\`

Result:

`\\some_server\a_resource\somelibrary.1\name_of_the_library.dll`

The problem is that the **\2** in the "replace with" string is considered as a match and it is replaced by "" (nothing), because there is no second match.

How can I escape the **"\2"** so the result is a slash and a 2??

Note: If a put **\\2** the results is **\**

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want this as your "Replace with" string:

```
\\\\some_server\\a_resource\\\1\\2.1\\
```

i.e. "...a_resource" + escaped backslash ("\\") + matched string 1 ("\1") + escaped backslash ("\\") + "2.1" + escaped backslash ("\\")

Edit:  needed a double-backslash before 'a_resource' and doubled the backslashes at the start.

Comment: It does not work. It seems that "Replace with" is a literal (except of course for the \{n})...

Comment: It provides exactly the output you desire on my machine, running Notepad++ 5.8.7.  I had to add a backslash because it was interpreting backslash-a as 'BEL'.  Replace is definitely *not* literal.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem, but I always do this in 2 steps:

- first replace with `\\\\some_server\\a_resource\\\1\\something_really_strange\\`
- then replace 'something_really_strange' with '2.1' in normal mode